# Do schools/universities in EU prefer to appoint PhD graduates as teachers from their own student pools?

Tags: phd, tenure-track, eu

As far as I understand, EU schools have high regards for PhDs from anglosphere, especially from USA and UK.

But, what about schools in EU itself?

Suppose,  an International student,

(1) has a bachelor, Masters, and PhD from a same school "X" in an EU country "A".
 (2) has a bachelor, Masters, and PhD from various schools "X", "Y", and "Z" in different EU countries: "A", "B", "C".

Does (2) make any difference if he has an intention of doing job in a school "X" as a teacher?

Do schools/universities in EU prefer to appoint PhD graduates from their own student pools?

Comment: Keep in mind language requirements in the EU: international stusents in my university are not allowed to teach because they don't have a good enough command of the local language.

Comment: I think as a general rule, people _prefer_ to bring in outsiders, just to broaden the base of ideas. My perspective is US, not EU, but it seems pretty universal to me. However, what they really want is the best available candidate.

Comment: @Thomas, what if the PhD graduate has a CEFR C1 proficiency?

Comment: @user366312: Yes, if they speak well enough, they could teacg, of course. ("Allowed" was too strong, better would be "there do at the time not teach international students".

Comment: My point is that language requirements are in my university the only requirement for teaching for phd students.

Comment: @Thomas, is it possible for you to reveal your university's name?

Comment: I should not (as they have no oppurtunity to defend themselves here). It is however, hard for me to imagine it being different in any EU country where education is not given in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each EU country has quite a different academic culture. Some are perceived as being quite insular, with a lot of hiring from within; some are considered "impenetrable" by outsiders; some are quite the opposite and offer significant perks to try to attract top notch scholars from outside. Each system has its quirks and it is impossible to talk about the differences without knowing which country you are speaking about here I'm afraid.

Speaking personally, I know that the Dutch university that I am about to move to has hired people in the same department as I will be in with degrees and research backgrounds in several other EU countries, but you can't really extrapolate that information out beyond the Netherlands.